# Eval giving inconsistent outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

While experimenting with the eval function in python I found that eval function was not working as I excepted it to do

when I passed `eval("(-0.02)**(1/3)")` the output was `(0.13572088082974537+0.23507546124511977j)`

but when `eval("-0.02**(1/3)")`was executed the output was `-0.2714417616594907`

I tried using positive numbers instead and it worked

```
eval("(0.02)**(1/3)")
0.2714417616594907

eval("0.02**(1/3)")
0.2714417616594907
```

Can someone explain what and why is it happening

Comment: ```-0.02**(1/3)```  is equivalent to ```-1 * (0.02)**(1/3)```

Comment: Different input, different output. Where is it inconsistent?

Comment: `(-0.02)**(1/3)` it is treated as a complex number. and `-0.02**(1/3)` this will treated as a real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `**` (exponentiation) has higher precedence than `-` (unary negation) (see the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)). As a result,

```
-0.02**(1/3)
```

is evaluated as

```
-(0.02**(1/3))
```

i.e.

```
-0.2714417616594907
```

By comparison, the `()` around `-0.02` in `(-0.02)**(1/3)` makes that the computation of the cube root of `-0.02`, which is `0.13572088082974537+0.23507546124511977j` (a complex number).

Note this has nothing to do with `eval`, you will get the same results by typing those expressions into the python interpreter.